# Contador Click JavaScript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou aplicando atributos e nomes de imagens via Jquery através de um array de imagens e nomes.
A imagem abaixo ilustra as imagens do array carregadas.

[image: Imagens carregadas pelo Array]

Quando eu clico exibo o nome da imagem contido no array.
Abaixo a imagem ilustra o que ocorre quando é realizado o evento click, os nomes são exibidos embaixo das imagens, no caso ai só duas imagens foram clicadas.

[image: Array de nomes carregado após evento click]

Tenho que contabilizar os clicks também. Porém não sei como realizar esse mesmo evento no código abaixo:

Meu código html esta assim:

`<div class="col-md-3">
    <figure class="catImag"><img src=""></figure>
    <span class="count"></span> onde vai o contador
</div>`

E esta é o meu jQuery com evento click.

```
 const catsImages = ['cat01.jpg', 'cat02.jpg', 'cat03.jpg', 'cat04.jpg', 'cat05.jpg'];
    const catsName = ['Cat KiKI', 'Cat Edi', 'Cat Didi', 'Cat Kely', 'Cat Vivi'];

    let image = [...catsImages];
    let name = [...catsName];

    console.log(image);
    console.log(name);

    let count = 0;//Variavel contador

    $.each($('.catImag img'), function(index) {
        $(this).attr({
            src: image[index],
            alt: name[index]
        });
    }); //Update Cat cria os atributos para receber a imagem

    $.each($('figure'), function(index, el) {

        $(this).one('click', function(event) {
            /* Act on the event */
            $(this).append('<figcaption>' + name[index] + '</figcaption>');
        });

    });// update click name, exibe o nome do cat clicado
```

Comment: Não entendi o uso desta linha: `let $span = $('img').append('<span>' + count + '</span>');`... vc quer fazer um append dentro de uma imagem? Uma imagem é um elemento fechado e não aceita append. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Essa linha eu esqueci de tirar era um teste que eu estava realizando. Ignore ela.

Comment: Removi a resposta. Tem que ajustar a pergunta com o código correto. Noa comentários vc está tirando e adicionando códigos. Tem é que editar a pergunta com o que vc quer e o código correto.

Comment: ok vou reformular a pergunta aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man tenta algo assim:

``

```
    </figure>
    <figure class="catImag">
    <img src="" alt="">
        
    </figure>
    <figure class="catImag">
    <img src="" alt="">
```

``

E esta é o meu jQuery com evento click.

var imageObject = [
{
src: 'cat01.jpg',
alt: 'Cat 01',
count: 0,
},
{
src: 'cat02.jpg',
alt: 'Cat 02',
count: 0,
},
{
src: 'cat03.jpg',
alt: 'Cat 03',
count: 0,
},
];

$('.catImag img').each(function(i, el) {

$(this).attr(
{
'src': imageObject[i].src,
'alt': imageObject[i].alt,
'data-count': imageObject[i].count
}
);

$(this).after('' + imageObject[i].alt + '');
$(this).after('');

})

$('.catImag ').click(function(){

```
var countIni = $(this).children('img').attr('data-count');

$(this).children('span').text(countIni = parseInt(countIni, 10) + 1);
$(this).children('img').attr('data-count',countIni)


console.log($(this).children('span'));

})
```

Comment: Hernani, eu entendi era melhor criar um array de objetos mesmo. retirei apenas a linha ``$(this).after('<figcaption>' + imageObject[i].alt + '</figcaption>');`` porque o nome não deve ser exibido antes do click. Somente no click. Obrigado mano. Você salvou o dia, o ano quero dizer. ;)

Comment: Eu mantive esta parte do código porque o nome é exibido após o click. 

``$.each($('figure'), function(index, el) {
        
        $(this).one('click', function(event) {
            / Act on the event /
            $(this).append('<figcaption>' + image[index].alt+ '</figcaption>');
        });
        
    });``

Comment: Então vc poderia colocar isso dentro do metodo que faz a contagem pq ele vai ser executado quando clicar do mesmo jeito e não precisaria rodar um $.each. Quando você escuta um evento o jquery te passa o elemento através do $(this), então vc nao precisa de um $each pra escutar evento..

Comment: Ok. Obrigado mano.